# How to parse <select><option> tag using HtmlAgilityPack

Tags: html

I am able to parse radio , checkbox etc.
but while parsing select nodes :

```
<select name="customeDropDown1" style="height :27px;width :121px;margin-top :75px;margin-left :401px;color:#000000;background-color:#FFFFFF;font-family:Roboto;font-style:;font-size:16px;position:absolute;">
<option>Option1
</option>
<option>Option1
</option>
<option selected="selected">Option1
</option>
</select>
```

I am able to get the select tag using

```
 var dropdowns = doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select");
 foreach (HtmlNode dropDown in dropdowns)
```

but not able to get the values in the option tag
I have tried

```
dropDown .InnerHtml
dropDown . InnerText
```

and

```
foreach (HtmlNode node in doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select//option"))
```

I have found that using Xpath it can be resolved, any code sample will be helpful.

I am using C# win form application.

Comment: and how to get the inner text of a text area ?

Comment: I'm also not able to parse the values from within the tags. Will post answer if i managed to do so

Answer (score 3):

For some weird reason, HtmlAgilityPack does not handles those  tags correctly, so this managed to solve my problem.

```
        // Iterating over nodes to build the dictionary
        foreach (HtmlNode city in citiesNodes)
        {
            if (city.NextSibling != null)
            {
                string key   = city.NextSibling.InnerText;
                string value = city.Attributes["value"].Value;

                citiesHash.AddCity (key,value);
            }
        }
```

Instead of reaching directly the node,i managed to get the values of each node by using the `NextSimbling` reference from the previous simbling.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try this. For anyone else that needs to try something different (the answer did not work for me), I ended up just referencing the child nodes from the parent:

```
HtmlNode.ElementsFlags.Remove("option"); // need this before you do anything with HAP

var options = htmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//select[@id='myselect']/option")
for (var i = 0; i < options.Count; i++) {
    var val = options[i].InnerHtml;
}
```

I was trying to do a foreach, iterating through the nodes, which was giving me null values. This works just fine for me.